# How to implement an API in SCP with Node.js and display on Browser

Tags: node.js, api, ide, httprequest, sap-web-ide

I am currently trying to learn Node.js and implementing my first API (I picked Chuck Norris API) in SAP Web IDE.
The following is the code that I found:

```
app.get("/chuckvar", (req, res) => {
    var http = require('https'),
        url = require('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random');
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        var query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
        res.end(JSON.stringify(query));
    });
});`
```

Until now I was able to display the content of the URL in the console but not on the browser which is my goal.

I wrote this code but I keep getting the same 
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S01sS.png).

So I need help to successfully implement the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "require" function purpose is to import [modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) (like the [https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) one when you do `require('https')`).

Your error message means that "require" expected the argument to be a node module (not an url).

To fetch an url content you can use the "[request](https://github.com/request/request)" module (witch is simpler to use that the [native one](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest)):

```
const request = require('request');
app.get("/chuckvar", (req, res) => {
    request('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random', function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
        console.log('body:', body); // Prints the body
        res.end(body); // Will forward the api response
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It worked!
If you have any tutorials or good source where I can learn more about this this topic, please let me know.
Thank you again!